# Amistad Mongoid Save Does Not Persist

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I'm just starting to get to use Amistad with Mongoid and I'm finding that current_user.invite(@user) is not saving to the Mongo. I've done this in the console and in the Rails application, which I've determined that the method does work, as the method returns true, but the data does not persist. Has anyone else had this problem? My mongo db does work. I've saved all sorts of data with it, but the Amistad friend methods are not.

Here's the controller action:

```
def invite_friend
  @user = User.find params['id']
  res = current_user.invite(@user)
  current_user.last_name = 'hamilton123'
  current_user.save

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    format.js{ render :js => "$('#friend_#{params['id']}').text('Pending')" }
  end
end
```

Here's some of the log output after the .invite() is run. I also did a current_user.save() just to make sure that I could see Mongo output a save

```
MONGODB yansn_development['system.namespaces'].find({})
MONGODB yansn_development['users'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4f8b100dbf0d820513000007')}).limit(-1).sort([[:_id, :asc]])
MONGODB yansn_development['users'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4f8b0fd2bf0d82055b000001')}).limit(-1).sort([[:_id, :asc]])
MONGODB yansn_development['users'].update({"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4f8b100dbf0d820513000007')}, {"$set"=>{"last_name"=>"hamilton123", "updated_at"=>2012-04-15 19:06:21 UTC}})
```

Shouldn't there be a save for the invite() method?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Amistad [source](http://rubydoc.info/gems/amistad/0.7.5/Amistad/ActiveRecord/FriendModel/InstanceMethods#invite-instance_method) the method will return false if the user is `self` or if a friendship already exists with the user, in the following manner:

```
def invite(user)
  return false if user == self || find_any_friendship_with(user)
  Friendship.new(:user_id => self.id, :friend_id => user.id).save
end
```

I would check to see if the User you are getting back with your `find` is actually the one you are expecting, and does not have an existing relationship with the user.